# Dynamically add and remove rows of cascading dropdown lists?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, frontend

So I'm trying to make a form where the user can dynamically add and remove rows containing cascading dropdowns as a class picker.

So far I've been able to make everything work except for the `remove selected classes` function.

I've tried a couple different `deleteRow` functions but can't seem to make it work.

My most recent attempt is by using the checkbox input but I'm open to any other solutions.

Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
        <title>Semesters Planned</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#selectCategory').change(function() {getSelectedItem(this, null); });
        $('#button').click(function() 
            {addRow('dataTable');   });         
    var classes = {//can probably use external text files for these later on
        "Core": ["UNI101", "ENG101"],
        "Major": ["CSC101", "CSC180"],
        "Elective": ["ART101", "PSY101"]
        };
    var keys = Object.keys(classes);
    var category_dropdown = document.getElementById("selectCategory");

    var getSelectedItem = function(element, row) {
        var e = element;
        var selectedCategory = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var sub_category_dropdown = (row != null ? row.getElementsByTagName("select")[1] : document.getElementById("selectSubCategory"));
            sub_category_dropdown.options.length = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < classes[selectedCategory].length; i++) {
            sub_category_dropdown[sub_category_dropdown.length] = new Option(classes[selectedCategory][i], classes[selectedCategory][i]);
    }
    };
        var addRow = function(tableID) 
    {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
    }
    var selects = row.getElementsByTagName("select");
    selects[0].addEventListener('change', function() 
    {
        getSelectedItem(this, row)
    }, false);

  };
  function deleteRow(tableID)
{
    for (var rowi= table.rows.length; rowi==0;) {
        var row= table.rows[rowi];
        var inputs= row.getElementsByTagName('chk');
        for (var inputi= inputs.length; inputi0;) {
            var input= inputs[inputi];

            if (input.type==='checkbox' && input.checked) {
                row.parentNode.remove(tableID);
                break;
}
}}}
  for (var keys in classes) {
    category_dropdown[category_dropdown.length] = new Option(keys, keys);
  }
});
</script>
   </head>

   <body>
    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Class" id="button" />
<INPUT type="button" value="Remove Selected Classes"/>
<form id="myForm">
  <TABLE id="dataTable">
    <TR>
      <TD>
        <select id="selectCategory">
          <option>Choose Class Type</option>
        </select>
      </TD>
      <TD>
        <select id="selectSubCategory">
          <option>Choose Class Type First</option>
        </select>
      </TD>
      <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" id="input"/></TD>
    </TR>
    
  </TABLE>
</form>

   <a href = "builder.html"><input type = "Submit" value = "Submit"> </a>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to make sure that the remove button is doing something when you click it - you've attached an event listener to the Add Class button, but the Remove Selected Classes button doesn't look like it's calling that deleteRows function.

Then, make sure that you have a reference to that table in the deleteRows function. You are passing it a table id, but the `table` variable reference is defined outside of the [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) of that function.

Then, work on the for loop and the logic therein. It looks like you are mistaking getElementsByTagName with [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName). The one you are using is concerned with the tag name (input) not the name attribute (chk).

Hope this helps a little bit!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For your first suggestion, would you recommend that I use another event listener or an onclick event?

Comment: I would just do what you did for the other button simply because it keeps things consistent. Then I would place some `console.log` statements inside that function and for loop so that you can work through the other issues there. Just go line by line and make sure the code is doing what you think it's doing.